# Identify OAuth for Multiple Google Accounts/Calendars

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-oauth

We have a chrome extension that adds on some information to certain Google Calendar meetings (based on user action).  To accomplish this, we perform an OAuth on the user logged into the Calendar, and use the Google API to add our information.

This works perfectly fine when only one Google account is being used for Calendar/GMail.  However, when there are multiple accounts (such as a personal and a Google Apps business account), we have to figure out which account owns a given calendar. We currently handle this by looking at DOM elements and tying it back to the correct account we have stored.  However, this is proving very fragile, and causes major pains when it fails.

We have also evaluated chrome.identity, but it appears that this is the information for the account logged into the Chrome browser itself, not the account active in the web session.

Is there a programmatic way to tell which Google user is active under these circumstances so we can make the appropriate api calls?

Comment: Maybe you can use [gapi.client.plus.people.get({'userId': 'me'});](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve_profile_information)?

Comment: doubt if above would work as the token wasnt probably issued to the plus scopes

Comment: try also this but may have the same issue I pointed above. grab the token from the cookie.  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#tokeninfo-validation

Comment: can't you simply query the calendar's acls and find the owner https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl#resource

Comment: Unfortunately none of these appear to do the job.  The token gives us the OAuth, but it doesn't solve the issue of which user is currently logged in, and the acl doesn't seem to return the current logged in user, just add access settings via api.  The real underlying issue we have is figuring out which account owns what I see at google.com/calendar right now, when users can switch between accounts.

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm having the same issue!